# How to detect URLs errors when trying to Chromecast an URL from an Android app?

Tags: android, error-handling, chromecast

I have an Android app that allows casting remote URLs via Chromecast.
This works fine, but I'm trying to provide feedback to the user when casting fails.
Right now I'm unable to get any error feedback via RemoteMediaClient.Callback
The onMediaError() callback isn't called even when the URL provided doesn't exist and returns an error 404.
How I can know about those error to provide some feedback to the user?

Comment: Are any of the other callback methods working? Say onSendingRemoteMediaRequest() ?

Comment: Yes everything else including other callback work fine. I can get a status error from onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated(), but there's no information associated to know what kind of error caused this

Comment: Instead of RemoteMediaClient.Callback, can you try using RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult and you can define getMediaError() there.

Comment: https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c7cb5a1ac38dc0001e4338f#L647.
This might help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but can you set this callback on your RemoteMediaClient

```
MediaInfo.Builder mi =
        bulider.setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .setMetadata(md)
                .setCustomData(j);

remoteMediaClient.load(mi, true, seekTo).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                        Log.d("cast", "SUCCESS");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                        Log.d("cast", "FAILURE "+status.getStatusMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I don't see any setResultCallback() method